# In c# how to stop the button from working when once all items of one listbox is transferred to other?

Tags: c#

The cause is when list box is empty and button is being clicked, the error pops up as there won't be any item to move from that list box.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace classdrill
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name;
            name = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            listBox2.Items.Add(name);
            listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about setting it to **button1.enabled=false;** ??

Comment: Once you've transferred the items, disable the button. If !Items.Any() then button1.Enabled = false

Comment: `button1.Enabled = listBox1.Items.Count > 0;`

Answer (score 3):

This checks to see if any left in list then deactivates button if there isn't any left.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name;
        name = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        listBox2.Items.Add(name);
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        if(0>=listBox1.Items.Count)
        {
            button1.enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: They want to disable the button

Comment: This is the correct place they want on button press if they run out of items then disable button this code compiles works and does what they want.

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo can you send us a list of valid places for this code

Comment: It does, but the button would be permanently disabled if directly following your code. You'd also need to ensure that the button is enabled again once the items in the listbox change

Comment: Then they would on other button that puts stuff in list to re-enable it there. Any idiot could work that out.

Answer (score 0):

After you remove the item from `listBox1`, check if the number of items in the `ListBox` is less than or equal 0. If so, disable the `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

Set Button's [`Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property to false

```
if(listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: guess same as mine look at my comments

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnButtonClick();
    }

    private void OnButtonClick()
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);

        button1.Enabled = listBox1.Items.Count > 0;
    }
```